# Detect if bat file is running via double click or from cmd window

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a bat file that does a bunch of things and closes the cmd window which is fine when user double clicks the bat file from explorer. But if I run the bat file from a already open cmd window as in cmd>c:\myfile.bat then I do not want the bat file to close the cmd window (END) since I need to do other things. I need bat dos command code that will do something like

```
if (initiated_from_explorer) then
else
endif
```

Is this possible ? thanks

Comment: Doesn't it close automatically when run from Windows Explorer?

Comment: As Michael said, what you desire is default behavior. Sounds like you have an explicit exit command at the end of your batch file. Don't.

Comment: It's the other way round - I wanted to keep a `pause` statement if launched from explorer, but not when launched from cmd.exe.

Comment: Something like @ECHO %CMDCMDLINE% | FIND /I /C "/C" > NUL && PAUSE should do it, unless the command window was opened in a bizarre way and contains "/C".

Comment: By the way, @ECHO %CMDCMDLINE% | FIND /I /C "/C" > NUL && TIMEOUT /T 9 (or whatever number of seconds) might be more useful to avoid cluttering up the desktop with lots of unclosed windows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`%cmdcmdline%` gives the exact command line used to start the current Cmd.exe.

- When launched from a command console, this var is `"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe"`.
- When launched from explorer this var is `cmd /c ""{full_path_to_the_bat_file}" "`;
  this implicates that you might also check the `%0` variable in your bat file, for *in this case* it is always the full path to the bat file, and always enclosed in double quotes.

Personally, I would go for the `%cmdcmdline%` approach (not `%O`), but be aware that both start commands can be overridden in the registry…

Comment: Works except that running `./batch.cmd` from powershell uses `cmd /c` under the hood :(

Answer (score 24):

[mousio's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5860983/119775) is nice but I did not manage to make it work in an "IF" statement because of the double quotes in the value of `%cmdcmdline%` (with or without double quotes around `%cmdcmdline%`).

In constrast, the solution using `%0` works fine. I used the following block statement and it works like a charm:

```
IF %0 == "%~0"  pause
```

The following solution, which expands `%~0` to a fully qualified path, might also work if the previous does not (cf. [Alex Essilfie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859854/detect-if-bat-file-is-running-via-double-click-or-from-cmd-window#comment96575380_18501554)):

```
IF %0 EQU "%~dpnx0" PAUSE
```

However, note that this solution with `%~dpnx0` fails when

1. the .bat file is located somewhere in the `%USERPROFILE%` directory, and
2. your `%USERNAME%` contains one or more uppercase characters

because... wait for it... the `d` in `%~dpnx0` forces your `%USERPROFILE%` username to lowercase, while plain `%0` does not. So they're never equal if your username contains an uppercase character. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

**[Edit 18 June 2021 - thanks to JasonXA]**

You can solve this lowercase issue with case-insensitive comparison (magic `/I`):

```
IF /I %0 EQU "%~dpnx0" PAUSE
```

This might be the best solution of all!

Comment: This is the most straightforward one in the lot. In my case, I found that I had to append a few more characters to the second parameter in order to expand it to a fully qualified path and get it to evaluate correctly. So, my final command was ```IF %0 EQU "%~dpnx0" PAUSE```.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie glad it can help, and thanks for the feedback. Solution updated.

Comment: Both of these checks can be tricked from the command line by calling the script by specifying the full path and putting quotes around it...

Comment: `IF %0 == "%~0" PAUSE` works fine for me, but `IF %0 EQU "%~dpnx0" PAUSE` fails when the .bat file is located somewhere in my `%USERPROFILE%` directory, because... wait for it... the `d` in `%~dpnx0` forces your `%USERPROFILE%` username to lowercase, while `%0` does not. So they're never equal if your username contains an uppercase character.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett  Another Jean-Francois editing my answer. What are the odds? Merci J-F.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Ha, I hadn't even noticed  XD  Pas d'prob

Comment: IF /I would solve different case comparisons.

Comment: Just checking %0 for surrounding quotes and making a decision based on that is problematic, because you could put the script in quotes in CMD as well (if the path includes space, you'd even HAVE to).

Comment: *'but I did not manage to make it work in an "IF" statement because of the double quotes'* – my solution to this problem: Just dropping these quotes: `if "%cmdcmdline:"=%" == "..."` – be aware that there's a trailing space left then which needs to be included in the comparison string.

Answer (score 9):

A consolidated answer, derived from much of the information found on this page:

```
:pauseIfDoubleClicked
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set testl=%cmdcmdline:"=%
set testr=!testl:%~nx0=!
if not "%testl%" == "%testr%" pause
```

1. The variable "testl" gets the full line of the cmd processor call (as per mousio), stripping out all of the pesky double quotes.
2. The variable "testr" takes "testl" and further strips outs the name of the current batch file name if present (which it will be if the batch file was invoked with a double-click).
3. The if statement sees if "testl" and "testr" are different.  If yes, batch was double-clicked, so pause; if no, batch was typed in on command line, go on.

Naturally, if you want to do something else if you detect a double-click, you can change the pause.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: As an extra benefit, this does also work when started as an administrator with the mouse.

Answer (score 8):

## Less code, more robust:

Build upon the other answers, I find the most robust approach to:

1. Replace quotes with `x` to enable text comparison without breaking the IF statement.
2. Recreate the expected cmdcmdline exactly (well, with '"' replaced by `x`).
3. Test for case-insensitive equality.

#### The result is:

```
set "dclickcmdx=%comspec% /c xx%~0x x"
set "actualcmdx=%cmdcmdline:"=x%"

set isdoubleclicked=0
if /I "%dclickcmdx%" EQU "%actualcmdx%" (
    set isdoubleclicked=1
)
```

This adds more robustness against general `cmd /c` calls, since Explorer adds an awkward extra space before the last quote/x (in our favor). If `cmdcmdline` isn't found, it correctly renders `isdoubleclicked=0`.

### Addendum:

Similarly to the above method, the following one-liner will pause a script if it was double-clicked from explorer. I add it to the end of my scripts to keep the command-line window open:

(**Edit 2022-01-12**, fixed quote mismatching [from this discussion](https://gist.github.com/maphew/9f6ba713d30eb1d0f67e7f0b2a338ba5))

```
if /i "%comspec% /c ``%~0` `" equ "%cmdcmdline:"=`%" pause
```

```
if /i "%comspec% /c %~0 " equ "%cmdcmdline:"=%" pause
```

Comment: I wanted the 'Addendum' one liner to work, but it doesn't for me. I found a solution but can't post in comments because markdown processing eats the backticks. I added it to this gist: https://gist.github.com/maphew/9f6ba713d30eb1d0f67e7f0b2a338ba5

Comment: @mattwilkie If you find the answer broken and are sure that your gist fixes it, then please go ahead and edit the answer

Comment: Thanks Simon. After posting that I discovered a situation where neither solution works. I'm still scratching my head trying to understand why, because the environments I'm testing should be identical, but from behaviour they're obviously not.

Comment: @mattwilkie It might be that internally `cmdcmdline` isn't actually built from `comspec` and that my assumptions and tests were wrong. I went on a hunch and found no counterexamples until you claimed one. We can also just strip the quotes completely, this might invite extra false positives (can't really see how though), but it will almost certainly lower false negatives. Does this work for your cases? `if /i "%comspec% /c %~0 " equ "%cmdcmdline:"=%"`

Answer (score 5):

Use `exit /b 0`, not `exit`

The former will exit all the way if launched from Windows Explorer, but return to the console if launched from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a command line parameter when running from a CMD window that won't exist when the file is double-clicked. If there is no parameter, close the window. If there is, don't close it. You can test the parameter using `%1`

Comment: Or you could have the parameter be on a shortcut to the batch file, and have the users double-click the shortcut instead of the actual batch file.  That way, if you forget the parameter, you don't accidentally lose your command window and all the history.

Comment: @mellamokb: I thought of that as well, but the OP specifically asked about double-clicking the batch file, so I didn't suggest a shortcut instead. I probably should have as an alternative after my original answer. Thanks.

Comment: thx. If the %cmdcmdline% solution fails I will go with this. In your solution I need to remember to pass a dummy param to the bat when I am in the cmd window.

Comment: @KenWhite This will fail when a file is dragged onto a batch file in Windows Explorer because the 1st parameter won't be empty then.

Comment: @mrt: Not if the command line parameter is unique. `/IwasrunfromCMD` works perfectly well. So you check for a *specific* command line parameter instead.

Comment: @KenWhite Ah this is what you've meant. I thought you suggested to test only whether a parameter was given or not. I think you should add this example to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only possible, but your desired behavior is the *normal* behavior of batch file execution, unless you do something 'special':

- when executing a batch file by double-clicking it in Explorer, the cmd window will close when it's done;
- when the batch file is executed from the command line, it simply returns to the command line prompt when complete - the window is not closed;

So I think the question that needs to be answered is what are you doing in the batch file that causes the command window to close when you execute it by the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Paste this at the beginning of your BAT or CMD script and maybe change what happens in the 'if' clause:

```
:: To leave command window open if script run from Windows explorer.
@setlocal
@set x=%cmdcmdline:"=%
@set x=%x: =%
@set y=%x:cmd/c=%
@if "%x%" neq "%y%" cmd /k %0 %* && exit || exit
@endlocal
```

What this does, is if the user either double-clicks or calls this script using "cmd /c" it will re-launch with  "cmd /k" which will leave the session open after the command finishes. This allows the user to EXIT or maybe do something else.

The reason for doing it this way rather than the other ways explained in this answer is because I've found situations that still even with using the quotes or other symbols, the IF statement would barf with certain situations of the QUOTES and the /c  and with spaces. So the logic first removes all QUOTES and then removes all spaces.. because SOMETIMES there is an extra space after removing the quotes.

```
set x=%cmdcmdline:"=%       <-- removes all quotes
set x=%x: =%                <-- removes all spaces
set y=%x:cmd/c=%            <-- removes  cmd/c  from the string saving it to  y
```

The point of the   && exit || exit   is so that if the ERRORLEVEL before exiting is 0 (success) it then stops running, but also if it is non 0 (some failure) it also stops running.

But you can replace this part:

```
cmd /k %0 %* && exit || exit
```

with something like

```
set CALLED_WITH_CMD_C=YES
```

and then make up your own differences in the rest of your script. You would have to then move or remove the   endlocal.

The '@' symbol at front just prevents the echo, which you can have if you want to test.
Do not use   echo on   or   echo off   as it changes the setting and affects all subsequent scripts that call yours.

Answer (score 1):

Like @anishsane I too wanted a pause statement if launched from explorer, but not when launched from a command window.

Here's what worked for me, based upon @mousio's answer above:

```
@SET cmdcmdline|FINDSTR /b "cmdcmdline="|FINDSTR /i pushd >nul
@IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    @echo.
    @echo Press ENTER when done
    @pause > nul
)
```

(Nothing original here, just providing a working example)

Answer (score 0):

@dlchambers was close but set didn't work since cmdcmdline isn't a defined environment variable in some cases, but this version based on his works great for me:

```
echo %cmdcmdline% | findstr /i pushd >nul
if errorlevel 1 pause
```

Answer (score 0):

after reading through the suggestions, this is what I went with:

```
set __cmdcmdline=%cmdcmdline%
set __cmdcmdline=%__cmdcmdline:"=%
set __cmdcmdline=%__cmdcmdline: =%
set __cmdcmdline=%__cmdcmdline:~0,5%
if "%__cmdcmdline%"=="cmd/c" set CMD_INITIATED_FROM_EXPLORER=1
set __cmdcmdline=
```

which conditionally sets the variable: `CMD_INITIATED_FROM_EXPLORER`

..and can subsequently be used as needed:

```
if defined CMD_INITIATED_FROM_EXPLORER (
  echo.
  pause
)
```

..but the issue regarding Powershell that [@Ruben Bartelink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11635/ruben-bartelink) mentions isn't solved:

> running `./batch.cmd` from Powershell uses `cmd /c` under the hood

Answer (score 0):

You also can check for `SESSIONNAME` environment variable.

As you see here that variable typically isn't set in Explorer window. When invoking from cmd it `SESSIONNAME` is set to `Console`. I can confirm this for Windows 10.

Unfortunately behaviour seems to be changeable: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2509192/clientname-and-sessionname-enviroment-variable-may-be-missing

Answer (score 0):

(Partly) Contrary and in addition to the accepted answer AToW (re `%cmdcmdline%`) and the top answer AToW (re `if /i %0 equ "%~dpnx0"`) in Win10 it is:

- **in CMD:**

  - in a `*.cmd` (here `_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd`):

    ```bash
    "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"

    if /I _pauseIfRunFromGUI[.cmd] EQU "C:\Users\Geri\_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd"
    ```

    `.cmd` is present if entered on the cmd line, which happens if you complete with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
  - in a `*.cmd` (`_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd`) that's `call`ed by a `*.cmd`:

    ```bash
    "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"

    if /I _pauseIfRunFromGUI[.cmd] EQU "C:\Users\Geri\_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd"
    ```

    Same as above.

    `.cmd` is present if called via `call _pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd`.

  In any way the comparison evaluates to *false* which is intended.
- **from GUI:**

  (Explorer and link on Desktop)

  - in a `*.cmd` (here `_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd`) that's launched from the GUI:

    ```bash
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\Geri\_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd" "

    if /I "C:\Users\Geri\_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd" EQU "C:\Users\Geri\_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd"
    ```

    This one is ***different to the accepted answer AToW*** which says just `cmd /c ""..." "`_!

    The comparison evaluates to *true* which is intended.
  - in a `*.cmd` (`_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd`) that's `call`ed by a `*.cmd` (here `calling.cmd`) that's launched from the GUI:

    ```bash
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\Geri\calling.cmd" "

    if /I _pauseIfRunFromGUI[.cmd] EQU "C:\Users\Geri\_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd"
    ```

    Different to above, since `calling .cmd` is in `cmdcmdline`, of course, not the one in which it is evaluated (`_pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd`).

    `.cmd` is present if called via `call _pauseIfRunFromGUI.cmd` within `calling.cmd`.

    The comparison evaluates to ***false*** which is ***not*** intended!

If the comparison is changed to:

```bash
if /i "%cmdcmdline:~0,31%"=="C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c " echo: & pause
```

everything works as expected.