# is it possible to distinguish when shell is run from command line or from other shell?

Tags: windows, cmd

For example I can directly call `myscript.cmd` or in other script I can put a line to myscript.

The reason is that if a script is run on it's own it dissapears as soon as it stop executing, so I can't see the result, so at the end I must add `@pause` but when I run it from another shell this causes annoyance since console window wouldn't exit that way.

So I look for some kind of 'if' condition to address this issue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859854/detect-if-bat-file-is-running-via-double-click-or-from-cmd-window

Comment: Wow, interesting.  I was never aware of %cmdcmdline% since it doesn't show up in a list of env variables.  There's your solution, rsk82.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your script paused when double-clicked (or by dropping files on it), but terminating the usual way when invoked from console:

```
@echo off

echo Hello World!

:: ...your ScriptCode...

(((echo.%CMDCMDLINE%)|find /I "%~0")>NUL)&&pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you create an environment variable like Stu suggested, you're not going to find any that do what you want.  You're going to need to write a small program that queries the parent process programmatically and returns a value your script can check.  If you're being run from Start->run your parent will be explorer.exe.  Otherwise it will be cmd.exe or some other exe.

Sample code to find the parent process can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ParentPID.aspx).

Comment: Visual Studio would be the usual choice on Windows.

Comment: I don't have. It cost money ? Right ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set it yourself?

```
SET RUNNINGFROMOTHERSHELL=YES
CALL MYSCRIPT.CMD
SET RUNNINGFROMOTHERSHELL=
```

In MyScript.Cmd:

```
IF "%RUNNINGFROMOTHERSHELL%"=="" GOTO NOPAUSE
PAUSE
:NOPAUSE
```

Comment: It makes no sense to manually set a variable when starting cmd.exe from start->run window, it's worse than pausing itself. Maybe I should look for variables that are different in those both situations but do not have purpose exactly for this.

Comment: You wouldn't when doing from Start->Run. That's kind of the entire point. There are no environment variables that are different, by the way. Try it.

Comment: I suppose you're right but I really do not understand how it works, where do I set this variable ? MyScript is what I run, what I click in explorer, but I also can run cmd.exe and then in there cd to the folder and run my sript, but it seems that I should put it in anoter file from where I call my script, what file ? Then I must remember what file to call when.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you meant you were calling it from a different CMD file. First part would go in that CMD, second in MyScript. To do what you want, see Carey's answer.