# Determine if the program is called from a script in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, sh

doa

```
#!/bin/sh
myexe
```

myexe

```
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    print 'from a script'
else:
    print 'not from a script'
```

OUTPUT (if i execute doa from terminal):

```
not from a script
```

OUTPUT (if i execute myexe from terminal):

```
not from a script
```

I want it to say '`from a script`' if executed from doa

Question: is it possible for myexe to know that it's being executed from a bash script?

Comment: I don't know of a way to detect if the files been called from a script (In theory, it is always called by a script, be it a batch script, the command line, of your mouse double clicking on it). You could instead pass it a parameter from the script to detect with `sys.argv[index]` and tell it where it has been called from.

Comment: A bash script as opposed to what? Your `sh` script? An interactive shell? When does it matter?

Comment: Seeing if stdout is a TTY is a common, sensible check because it lets you decide whether to output in a human-readable or computer-readable format (e.g., colored output when connected to a TTY, plain output when piped to another process). But checking how your program is invoked... what would you do differently based on the identity of the parent process–and **why**?

Comment: from your terminal vs called from a script

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no.  What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski The problem is that myexe is suppose to say it's from a script if it is not called directly from terminal. tty check works with most scripts except shell script, it seems

Comment: "The problem is that myexe is suppose to say it's from a script if it is not called directly from terminal."  Yes.  That's what you asked.  But why?  Why is it so important to know?

Comment: Did you try to redirect output to a file and see what it says then? Cause if you invoke it from a script whose output is a terminal then it transitively means the output of your exe is also a terminal.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `psutil` to ask for the name of the process with id the parent process id:

```
import psutil
import os

ppid = os.getppid() # Get parent process id
psutil.Process(ppid).name() == "bash"
```

You can install `psutil` with `pip` command:

```
pip install psutil
```

Comment: If the user's console is also bash, then this won't be able to determine if it is being run from a script or if it's run directly from the console...

Comment: i know i gave bash as an example but i want to encompasses whole script.  myexe can be called from another python script or whatnot

Comment: @BillLynch can you check if the user console is bash or not and then compare against it? oh wait nvm.. hmm..

Comment: @ealeon: You can usually tell if the user console is bash by checking `$SHELL`. But personally, all of this is a bad idea.